# Running javascript inbetween php tags

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to run a javascript inbetween php tags, but I am not quite sure how to call it. All googling results in client side vs server side questions.

```
?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function extend() {
                        var temp = document.getElementById("search-menu").offsetHeight+1160;
                        document.getElementById("search-menu").style.height = temp."px";
                    }
                    extend();
                </script>
<?php
```

Here you can see the end of one php tag, and at the bottom, the start of the next tag. Inside is the script and a call to the function, but as of now, its not running. Am I calling the function improperly?

Comment: and why u want to do like that :)

Comment: I am doing it like this because it is the best way I can do it as of this moment. My web dev skills are still growing. If you have a better suggestion, I am willing to give it a try.

Comment: Technically yes mixing things together like that should be fine (not necessarily best practices, depending on the use-case but it should work in a pinch). 

Try isolating the problem. Change your JS to something more simple, like an alert() or a console.log(). See what happens.

Comment: can u please give the proper scenario or what exactly u want to do,so that we can give u better suggestion regarding your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing visibly wrong with that code is that you are trying to concatenate two variables using `.` instead of `+` (for which you should see a `Syntax Error: Unexpected String` message in your JS console).

There may be other issues, but they would be with how it interacts with the HTML you aren't showing us.

---

You can test to see if the interactions with PHP are as you expect by using the View Source feature of your browser to look at the code output from PHP that is sent to the server.

Comment: That fixed it, tyvm. Forgive my stupidity, 10hours of php coding messes with a guy... ^-^

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
temp."px";
```

To

```
temp+"px";
```

That's it :)